# How my Web server can send Web requests to my IoT thing?

Tags: web, iot

CAUTION: A newbie about [IoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things) concepts here!

I'll try to be short and explain what I want to do:

- Suppose that I already have connected my development board (be whatever you want; [arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/), [rpi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/), [esp8266](http://www.esp8266.com/). The only requirement is to have a WiFi module on it) to my electric water heater.
- I return from my work and I want the water to be ready for my bath.
- The only thing I do is to visit (via my amazing smartphone) `mywaterheater.herokuapp.com/manage/` and just press the `button` named `activate`!
- Bang! The development board has **received** a Web request from a User-agent, it activates the relay and my water heater is now turned on.

Can this be accomplished?

I suspect that I have to turn my dev board to a router in order to listen for Web requests (GET, POST, PUT). Is the [WoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_Things) trying to solve this kind of things?

It is assumed that any authentication/authorization and security issues have been taken care of.

Comment: Your question is too broad and you'd probably have better luck on http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to listen for HTTP requests, an HTTP server should be started on the board. Depending on the board type there could be different options, for example:

- [NodeMcu](http://nodemcu.com/index_en.html) firmware for ESP8266 has built-in HTTP server;
- [Web Server](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer) with Arduino and Ethernet
  Shield;
- [Multiple choices](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/) for Raspberry Pi.

After you enable a server on the board, it will listen for incoming requets on the specified IP and port. Assuming that your board will be placed in your local network, you will have to setup port forwarding to that IP:port on your router. You will also need external IP from your service provider to be able to access your board from the Heroku application.

Next step is to add HTTP client to your Heroku application that will send requests to the board. Again there are a lot of different options. As an example, if your app is written in Python, than you can use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library for this.

So when you will press a button on a web page served by Heroku, a HTTP client from your application will send a request to the IP address of your router. Then it should reach HTTP server on your board because of the port forwarding on the router.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! *You will also need external IP from your service provider to be able to access your board from the Heroku application.*. Sorry, but what do you mean by that? A static IP?

Comment: IP address should be public as opposed to the private one (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). Some service providers may use NAT with private addresses which will not allow you to make incoming requests. Public IP may be static or dynamic. With the latter you will also need to use dynamic DNS service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a lot of IoT device has web server framework. You can trigger IO from web request. But you need accsess the device from internet (port forwarding, static ip or dynds). Also there are generic smart phone app.